# Autoresizingmask

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Необходимо расширять `view` в зависимости от устройства, если выставляю маску в `storyboard` то все работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если прописывать в коде

```
viewTest.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

То при переходе с SE на iPhone 7 `view` не расширяется, думаю проблема в том, что надо задать где то, что расширять надо с SE, но вот как это сделать не знаю.

Comment: Почему не используете AutoLayout?

Comment: Привык к маскам.